# Is there a debian-sys-maint equivalent in centos?

Tags: centos, mysql, debian, database-backup

I am using debian-sys-maint as practical way to do database dumps in our debian systems, somenthing like this:

```
mysqldump -u debian-sys-maint -p`cat /etc/mysql/debian.cnf | grep password | tail -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f3`
```

I would like to know if there is a similar user to this in CentOS, I just need the user to be able to make backups. This way I don't have to create a new user on every system.
The interesting part of this is that /etc/mysql/debian.cnf contains the clear password for the debian-sys-maint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such MySQL user created by default in CentOS.

Comment: That's a pity, then how is it handled when doing an upgrade from i.e. mysql 4.1 to 50 (where there are queries involved) or the mysqlcheck that needs to be done in case a table crashed? Or the log rotations? In debian all this stuff is being/can be done with the debian-sys-maint user. For all those actions you are prompted for the mysql root password?

Comment: Major version upgrades must be performed by the user manually, since a given distro version will not contain a major version upgrade. The other operations are left to the sysadmin to prepare for.

Comment: I accept you solution, alought it sadly confirms that I will have to precreate a user for dumps in all the centos I manage. Thanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

debian-sys-maint user is by default a root equivalent on RHEL/CentOS. root exists on any mysql installations.

Comment: The interesting part is that on every debian install there's the password for that user in /etc/mysql/debian.cnf, so the database dumps can be scripted even when you don't know the password for the root user.

Comment: You need to have Linux root access to be able to read the contents of `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`.  But as you said, you don't need the MySQL ` root` password, as `debian-sys-maint` is equvivalent to MySQL `root` user.
I would make a backup user anyway, as that would not have write access to all databases, just read.